# Cookies not received by browser

Tags: node.js, json, express, axios

I'm having trouble with sending cookies to browser, I don't know why, in Postman is working fine, but in browser cookies are not received.
This is the function for creating and sending token:

```
const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id);
  const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    httpOnly: false
  };
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') cookieOptions.secure = true;

  res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);

  // Remove password from output
  user.password = undefined;

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
      user
    }
  });
};
```

And this is the function for login:

```
exports.login = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // 1) Check if email and password exist
  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new AppError('Please provide email and password!', 400));
  }
  // 2) Check if user exists && password is correct
  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

  if (!user || !(await user.correctPassword(password, user.password))) {
    return next(new AppError('Incorrect email or password', 401));
  }

  // 3) If everything ok, send token to client
  createSendToken(user, 200, res);
});
```

Also, I'm using axios for the login part and there may be the problem, I'm not sure. This is the login.js file:

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
  console.log(email, password);
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login',
      data: {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }
    });
    console.log(res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data);
  }
};

document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  login(email, password);
});
```

Comment: Add `domain` to the cookie with value of URL where your frontend runs?

Comment: I modified like this: ```const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    httpOnly: false,
    domain: 'http://localhost:3000/login'
  };```    But still not working.  In the visual studio console i get `[Object: null prototype] {}`